# Predicting variance or standard deviation in a regression

Tags: regression, variance

I am trying to run a regression that predicts the sample variance (or the sample standard deviation, either is fine) as a function of other variables, e.g.,

$Var(Y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + ... \epsilon $

What is the best way to specify this model? Obviously the dependent variable is bounded at 0, but I don't think zero-censored models are the way to go here. The sample variance is a chi squared distribution, so my guess is that a Gamma regression might be appropriate here. Is that right?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you mean that you want to estimate $\text{Var}(Y\vert X)$ instead of the more common $\mathbb E[Y\vert X]?$ Or do you have measurements of variances at particular values of $X?$

Comment: I have data indexed $1, ... , I$ that can be put into groups $1, ... J$ where $J < I$. So I want to take as a dependent variable the sample variance in each group ($Y_j$), and predict it from certain group-level covariates ($X_j$). Does that help?